# Using javascript in PowerPoint hyperlinks

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office-js

I have a web page that wraps a PowerPoint Online embedded viewer (iframe), and I'd like to communicate click events on PowerPoint elements up to my wrapper page.

I can't directly attach event handlers due to cross-domain issues, so I was hoping to add hyperlinks in the PowerPoint slides like `javascript:top.doSomething()`.  However, these links appear to be removed once the file is uploaded to SharePoint.

Is there anything I can do to enable these types of links in SharePoint, or is there another supported way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported. Allowing JS to be embedded within the PPT would simply present too many security concerns.

Depending on the exact scenario, you might be able to handle this scenario using web add-ins. An add-in could communicate to a common backend; allowing you to effectively relay information between the two environments.

Comment: I originally explored the content add-in route, but ultimately decided against having that dependency.  The exact scenario I'm trying to solve is to avoid having the PPT links open new windows, presumably because the links to my wrapper page are a different domain.  If I could communicate up to the wrapper page, then it could just update the iframe URL, giving me better control over the experience.